# ObjectContext object error- EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two tables written in EF CodeFirst:

```
public class DayType
{
 [Key]
 public int DayTypeID { get; set; }
 public string NameDayType { get; set; }        
 public virtual ICollection<SpecialDay> Specialdays { get; set; }
 public DayType() { }
}
public class SpecialDay
{
 [Key]
 public int SpecialDayID { get; set; }
 public int Year { get; set; }
 public int JanuaryDay { get; set; }
 public SpecialDay() { }
 public int? DayTypeId { get; set; }
 public virtual DayType daytype { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext relation one-to-many were made by FluentAPI:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<DayType>().HasMany(p => p.Specialdays).WithOptional(p => p.daytype);
```

This code throw exception. The purpose of function is to update entity. While debugging `sd` had all properties. sd - is object which were selected from datagrid and then changed.

```
internal void Update(SpecialDay sd)
{
   using (SalDBContext _db = new SalDBContext())
   {
      var newsd = _db.SpecialDays.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SpecialDayID==sd.SpecialDayID);
      newsd.JanuaryDay = sd.JanuaryDay;
      ....
      newsd.DecemberDay = sd.DecemberDay;
      newsd.DayTypeId = sd.DayTypeId;
      newsd.daytype = sd.daytype;
      try
      {
          _db.SaveChanges();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
   }
```

At these point exception is happened `_db.SaveChanges();`  Exception:

> {"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Would be thankful for any help with solution for my problems. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception states,

> "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."

Looking at the code you have there, you are assigning the `daytype` from the one passed in to the one you pulled from the database. Because you're creating a new `SalDBContext` every time you call into the `Update` method, you're assigning the `daytype` across `ObjectContext` objects (per the error message.

To get around that, you just need to eliminate that assignment in your `Update` method. Because you're assigning the FK ID in the property, you do not also need to assign the object.

One other note on EF, there is also a [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method which will go just by the ID instead of `FirstOrDefault`. It's a bit more optimized.

```
internal void Update(SpecialDay sd)
{
    using (SalDBContext _db = new SalDBContext())
    {
        var newsd = _db.SpecialDays.Find(p => p.SpecialDayID==sd.SpecialDayID);
        newsd.JanuaryDay = sd.JanuaryDay;
        ....
        newsd.DecemberDay = sd.DecemberDay;
        newsd.DayTypeId = sd.DayTypeId;
        // newsd.daytype = sd.daytype; Must be eliminated!
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have loaded `sd` (*from method head*) with anonther context as the one in your method body `newsd`. Therefore you received an exception on calling `_db.SaveChanges();`. I would say in line `newsd.daytype = sd.daytype;`, because it's a complex data type and represents one of your entities. Remove the line and set only the ID or load the obejct `sd` again for referencing.

Modified version of yours:

```
internal void Update(SpecialDay sd)
{
    using (SalDBContext _db = new SalDBContext())
    {
        var newsd = _db.SpecialDays.FirstOrDefault(p => p.SpecialDayID==sd.SpecialDayID);
        newsd.JanuaryDay = sd.JanuaryDay;
        // ...
        newsd.DecemberDay = sd.DecemberDay;
        // set only the id to reference the object
        newsd.DayTypeId = sd.DayTypeId;
        // newsd.daytype = sd.daytype;
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Well I was some seconds to late. :)